# SelectList Value

Tags: visualforce, selectlist

I have a selectlist that has a value of the opportunity stage.  I am trying to control what stage values display so that the user cannot use one that is not appropriate.

The problem I have is that when you first open the visualforce page, there are times that selectlist is not displaying the current value.  That seems to be dependent on the order of my method to create the Wstages variable.

It always makes the value the first one that was added.  Is there a way to update the default value of the sle

```
 <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!opp.StageName}" required="false" styleClass="required">
     <apex:actionSupport 
         event="onchange" 
         rerender="entirePage"
         status="showSpinner()"
    />  
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Wstages }"/>
 </apex:selectList>
```

```
I have a selectlist that has a value of the opportunity stage.  I am trying to control what stage values display so that the user cannot use one that is not appropriate.  The problem I have is that when you first open the visualforce page, there are times that selectlist is not displaying the current value.  That seems to be dependent on the order of my method to create the Wstages variable.  It always makes the value the first one that was added.  Is there a way to update the default value of the select list so it matches teh opp.StageName on load?  thanks!!

<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!opp.StageName}" required="false" styleClass="required">
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                            rerender="entirePage"
                            status="showSpinner()"/>  
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Wstages }"/>
             </apex:selectList> 

 public List<selectOption> buildMapOfRecordTypes() {
    //Set the values for the stages
    Wstages = new List<SelectOption>();

        if(opp.stagename.contains('Closed')){
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('', '- This Opp is Closed -')); 
        }
        else if(opp.stagename == 'Sales Proposal Prep'){
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('', '- Select a new stage -')); 
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('Sales Proposal Prep', 'Sales Proposal Prep'));
        }
            //only add other values if a product has been added to the opportunity
        if (opp.total_products__c >=1) {
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('In Underwriting', 'In Underwriting')); 
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('Released To Sales', 'Release To Sales'));
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('Released To Client', 'Release To Client'));   
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('Renewed', 'Renewed'));
            Wstages.add(new SelectOption('Terminated', 'Terminated'));
        }
    return Wstages;
 }
```

Comment: when the selectList is initially rendered, it will use the value in `opp.StageName` . So, without seeing how `opp` is set, hard to answer this question. Use [edit] to amend your question

Comment: Thanks cropredy.  I know the value of the selectlist is correct.  I put an inputfield for the stagename on the field and that shows the correct value.  I think my issue is that the select list is showing a different "selected" value that happens while I am setting the selectoptions.  Thanks!

Comment: the rerender will cause the getter on `opp` to be re-executed so that could be smashing the value of the new `opp.StageName`  (like maybe you are refetching from the database)